# concatenate hover in out jQuery

Tags: jquery, hover

I remember that one time I saw a jQuery in/out hover concatenation like this:

```
$('.xxx').hover(function(){
    $(this).css({'background':'white'});
}).(function(){
    $(this).css({'background':'red'});
});
```

But does not work.. what I'm doing wrtong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
$('.xxx').hover(function(){
    $(this).css({'background':'white'});
}, function(){
    $(this).css({'background':'red'});
});
```

You want to supply two handlers to the hover jQuery function. The first function is triggered when the mouse pointer enters the element. The second function is triggered when the mouse pointer leaves the element (https://api.jquery.com/hover/).

Comment: Is this way of coding deprecated or still valid and well compatible?

Comment: Definitely not deprecated and it's a perfectly reasonable way of accomplishing certain things. It obviously always depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Are there some contraindications?